# How to use `JOIN` to filter record?

Tags: join, influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

My time series data is stored in InfluxDB and SQL DB. The influxdb only stores a numeric key plus timestamp & value. All related info regarding the numeric key is stored in SQL DB.

InfluxDBb
datetime - timestamp
cnlnum - tag, string
val - value, float

SQL
id - int, this equals to int(cnlnum)
object - string
name - string

Am following the textbook example in Doc to query influx by conditions in the SQL table. But however I do it, the result is always `no result`.

I already confirmed that both queries return result before `JOIN` both have the common column `cnlnum`.

My query is as below:

```
import "sql"
_s1 = sql.from(
  driverName: "sqlserver",
  dataSourceName : ""
  query: "SELECT str(id) cnlnum FROM prof_incl_auto WHERE name like "RUN_STATE%"
)

_s2 = from(bucket: "data_30d")
  |> range(start: ... , stop: ... )
  |> filter( fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "sensor_data")

join(tables: {s1: _s1, s2: _s2}, on: ["cnlnum"])
```

Comment: There are 3 double quotes on line 5. Did you really run this code? What exactly does "result is always `no result`" mean? Are you looking at all error & warning messages from all layers? Debug one layer/language at a time, show each works & that data is passed correctly until you find the layer with an error. [mre] [ask] [help]

Comment: Yes I did run the code, I typed the whole post on my phone, due to connectivity issue. It's hard to keep it typo free. By no result, I mean when running the query in webUi the result is "no result". I am new to Flux, I can't find tools like EXPLAIN in SQL, I don't know what is going on behind the query. but both subquery returns result as expected, if executed separately without the = assignment ahead.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on all that you can in my 1st comment. Especially about isolating the error to a level. And give code we can cut & paste & run & get your result.

Comment: I don't think the setup or schemas matter, I this case. The question here is about JOIN. I will post the separate query result from CLI when I managed to logon Stackoverflow on PC.